# `Importlib` not actually importing modules?

Tags: python, import, module, python-importlib

I'm trying run an `env_setup` script that imports modules used in my `main_script`. But despite successfully running `env_setup.py` the modules are not being imported (presumably it is being run in its own environment).

Previously I know I have somehow sucesfully used:

```
from env_setup import *
```

However this fails for me now.

I tried a second approach using:

```
importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name, location)
```

But this also fails.

Below is an example of what I am attempting (using the second approach in my `main_script.py`):

**Example** `env_setup.py` **script**:

```
import datetime # import module
print("modules imported!!!") # confirm import
```

**Example** `main_script.py` **script**:

```
# This first section should import `datetime` using `env_setup.py`
import importlib
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
       name='setup',
       location='/home/solebay/my project/env_setup.py' # path to `set_up` script
       )
my_mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(my_mod)
# This returns "modules imported!!!"

# Here we run a basic command to check if `datetime` was imported...
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime('%H:%M:%S on %A, %B the %dth, %Y')) # Should print time/date
# NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

How do I get python to actually import the required modules into the environment running `main_script.py`? It creates a `__pycache__` folder so I know the path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

After dynamically importing a module you can either access the module directly by using `my_mod.function()` or import everything (imitate `from module import *`) like so:

```
import sys
sys.modules["setup"] = my_mod
from setup import *
del sys.modules["setup"]  # Optional
```

Answer (score 1):

After lots of searching I decided:

```
from env_setup import *
```

Should **absolutely** work.

I moved my most recent scripts to a fresh directory with a simpler tree and everything works.

I'm thinking it was a bug?

---

**Update** (*Not a bug*):

As per the useful suggestion of Bharel I ran..

```
import os
os.getcwd() # Returned 'wrong' directory
os.listdir() # Returned 'wrong' listing
```

Visual inspection of the folder tree showed that `env_setup.py` was present, but this file and others were absent from the true listing returned by `os.listdir()`.

I'm running my code through the IDE "Atom" using the "Hydrogen" module. I opened a new window, added a new project folder and ran the command again and it updated.

I'm assuming I moved a folder and Atom didn't have a chance to update the path.

**End result:**

```
from env_setup import *
```

Works prefectly.

Comment: It's not a bug, show us the directory listing and where were you running Python from (os.getcwd())

Comment: Thank you, I updated my answer. Not a bug.